# how to implement di for viewpager with dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-viewpager, dagger

i have a main acivity and have a viewpager in main activity.
viewpager have 4 similar fragment with this difference that each fragment have referrence to another retrofit api.
i use dagger2 for di.
my problem is that for each fragment should create module and component or can make one module and component for all.
if possible, in each fragment Must inject that.
thanks